# Get related objects attributes

Tags: django, django-templates

Im trying to make somekind of menu builder, where one model can be selfassigned with `ForeignKey`.

```
    class MainMenuItem(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = "menu_item"
            verbose_name = 'Раздел'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Разделы'     
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        parentFolder = models.ForeignKey('self', unique=False, related_name="childrenFolders", blank = True, null = True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

And now I'm stacked with a really simple thing...) But anyway... I can't get items, wich assigned to the another item. I wrote that in my template:

```
    {% for item in menuItems %}

        <li>{{item.childrenFolders.all}}</li>

    {% endfor %}
```

and got an array `[<MainMenuItem: item1>, <MainMenuItem: item2>, <MainMenuItem: item3>]`

But what I need to write after `childrenFolders.all...` to get a `title` field? Cause when i write something like `childrenFolders.all.item.title`, I got nothing...

Comment: Surely you need to iterate over that array, just as you iterate over menuItems in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for item in menuItems %}
    {% for childItem in item.childrenFolders.all %}
        <li>{{childItem.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```